# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '\\(x**x)**y'

Tags: python, numpy, math, symbolic-math

```
import math, numpy as np, random as rand, re
# x, y are variables; z is the mode (or operation) that'll be done with "x" and "y".

def hyperoperatio():
    #Variables
    a = 1
    var = []
    
    x = input("Inserte número 1: ")
    y = input("Inserte número 2: ")
    z = input("Inserte modo: ")
    log = input("¿Ud. prefiere que solo muestre las cifras del número? Sí (Y) o No (N): ")
    
    #Formato de las variables (aunque en hyper más altas -de pentación en adelante-
    #es mejor configurar todas las variables a formato int, ya que es más fácil de calcular).
    x = float(x)
    y = float(y)
    z = int(z)

    #Variables con valores específicos en las matemáticas, son importantes y les reservo un espacio.
    specialvars = {
            "pi" : math.pi,
            "e" : math.e
            }

    print("x es igual a:",x,"e y es igual a:",y)

    def hyper(x,y,z):

        #Diccionarios con instrucciones para el programa (y además orienta al programador).
        #Lo malo es que los resultados de los diccionarios son cargados totalmente aunque no sea
        #necesario. Por ahora, no introduzca números muy grandes en "x" o "y". Ahora los str no son convertibles en float o int.

        #Hiperoperaciones corrientes, volviéndose recursivo desde la tetración en adelante

        operati = {
            -4 : "\\1/((x**x)**y)",
            -3 : "\\1/(x*y)",
            -2 : "x/y",
            -1 : "x-y",
            1 : "x+y",
            2 : "x*y",
            3 : "\\x**y",
            4 : "\\(x**x)**y"
            }

        global a

        #Elección de modos

        if z == 0:

            a = rand.randint(0,1)

        elif z >= -4 and z <= 4:

            a = float(operati[z])
            print(a)

        elif z == 5:

            var.append(y)

            y = x

            b = int(operati[4])

            y = var[0]

            a = (b**b)**y
            
            print(a)

        print("El resultado es:",a)

    hyper(x,y,z)

    var.clear()
    
hyperoperatio()
```

How do I convert the elements of the dictionary "operati" so I can use the mathematical expressions as such? Without converting each meaning of that dictionary to a str, the program doesn't let me use the variables "x" and "y" with values that are over 5.

I also tried to use the backlash ("\") to solve that problem, but it didn't work. I don't know which character/s are causing the

Comment: Please post the actual error with traceback

Comment: `float()` can only be used with actual numeric values, such as a string `"1.5"` or an integer `99`.  You cannot use a formula in string form such as `"x * y"`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Cause

The reason you are getting an error is because you are trying to convert data to a type that it can't be converted to. To understand that, let's observe this line of code:

```py
int("aaaa")
```

That wouldn't work, because there is no implementation of casting a `string` to an `int`.

#### Solutions

I'll suggest two solutions, but I really only recommend the first.

##### Create a function for each operation

Instead of keeping the mathematical representation of each operation as items of a `dict`, create a function for each operation, that will accept `x` and `y` as paramaters. Something like:

```py
def operation_add(x, y):
  return x + y
```

If you really like the idea of using a `dict`, you could store references to these functions in a `dict` like so:

```py
operati = {
1: operation_add,
2: operation_mul
}
```

You'll just need to cast the input you get to the proper types before storing them into variables:

```
x = float(input("Inserte número 1: "))
```

##### Eval

Another option is to use the function `eval`. This is generally considered a bad practice, especially when used with user input involved, but make your own choices. If you don't need your code to be secure or stable it can work.

What `eval()` does is to take a string, and interpret it as if it were code.
For example:

```py
x = 5
y = 2
print(str(eval(r"x * y")))
```

Would print out `10`.
If you insure that `x` and `y` have the proper values and are casted to the proper type, you could just do something like:

```py
a = eval(operati[z])
print(a)
```